# the window close event, not run in a window without the window manager?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to execute a function with the closing event: `self.toplevel_1.protocol ('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: self.close_windows (3))` but it does not execute, I have thought that it has to do with the window manager since it I have removed and I have an independent closing button, I have looked for some other closing event for windows without the **window manager** but I can't find it, I would like to know if there is any closing event for this case, thank you very much.

```
def windows_open(self):
    self.Toplevel_3 = Toplevel(self)
    #self.toplevel_3 .protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',
                     lambda: self.close_windows(3))  # ancient
    self.toplevel_STUF.bind('<Destroy>',lambda e: self.close_windows(3))

def close_windows((self,  number, event=None):
    var = event.widget()
    if number is 3:
        if var is:    # How `var` gives an error, I don't know what it returns, here I stay 
            self.toplevel_3. destroy()
            self._open_3 = False
    #.....
```

Comment: `self.toplevel_3. destroy()`, why the space there?

Comment: In ```close_windows()``` function, does ```self.toplevel_3.quit()``` work instead of ```self.toplevel_3.destroy()```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WM_DELETE_WINDOW protocol and other protocols are specifically related to window manager protocols. If you don't have a window manager, they don't apply.

From the [protocol man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/wm.htm#M58):

> This command is used to manage window manager protocols...

In the absence of a window manager, you can bind to the `<Destroy>` event which should fire whether you have a window manager or not. You have to be careful with this if you bind to the root window. Bindings on the root widget or a `Toplevel` will apply to all descendant widgets, so in the bound function you'll want to run code only if `event.widget` refers to the root or `Toplevel` window.

Comment: In addition I would share my experience that the function that is bind to destroy of the root window event shouldn't be a long run, otherwise it throws an error.